# How to get input field value without using form in Python

Tags: python

I need to fetch input field value using python and that field not inside the form using `name/id` attribute. My code is below:

home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<center><h1>Welcome</h1></center>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{sid}}">
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    """ This function provides the home page ."""

    pers = User.objects.get(pk=request.session['id'])
    user_name = pers.uname
    return render(request, 'bookingservice/home.html',
                {'username': user_name, 'count': 1,'sid':request.session['sid']})
```

Here I need to get that hidden field value so that I will compare with the 
`request.session['sid']` within `if statement`.

Comment: have you tried to implement using js?

Comment: No,I have not implemented js yet. Can you share your answer by post.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
pers = User.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get("id"))
```

may be it will help you

Comment: where is post method here.